# Storing a music playlist, best approach?

Tags: database-design, users

I am working on a web project that creates playlists online based on youtube links.

My question is how do I store a playlist on MYSQL. What I was thinking about doing was having a table with basically all information. something like this

[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bTa0.png)

I could query this and get information "WHERE playlist_name=bob" and get every song in bobs playlist. Does this seem like a good route? Is it a problem that the table will eventually get huge? what about storing each playlist in a separate table, so bobs_playlist would be a whole new table. This would end up with MANY tables, is that a problem? are both approaches valid? is one better than the other? I just cant determine the best way to organize the information.

Answer (score 4):

I would approach it with this structure:

[image: Diagram]

This way you can have a more normalized structure, non-repeating data and simple tables.

In this method you would also be using WHERE PlaylistID=[bobs playlist id] instead.

With this structure's simplicity, you wont have to worry about any size issues for a long time. This structure will quickly handle millions of records. If you get bigger than that you can look into partitioning; that's not necessary for now.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider treating the records in Playlist_videos like a doubly linked list by adding a previous and next field pointing to the appropriate Playlist_videosID.

Using this approach, if you want statistics about the list (such as track number, etc...), you may need something more advanced. If you use something like Django, django-treebeard and django-mptt handle the insertion overhead by indexing to make querying faster. In any case, these libraries are a good starting point for understanding those advanced techniques.

The shortcoming of Andrew's approach with a track ordering ID becomes evident if you want to reorder the playlist. When you have a playlist of millions of songs and you want to insert a track, you would have to update the track number on every row until the end of the playlist.